# Simple Full Screen Mapbox map with svelte

Tags: javascript, mapbox, svelte

I want to display a very basic map with mapbox using svelte.
I am already failing when I just want to make the map full screen. I know there is the `svelte-mapbox` plug in. But I really do not want to do any fancy things. Just a full screen map for now;)

So my `main.js` looks defaultish like this:

```
import App from "./App.svelte";
const app = new App({
  target: document.body,
});
export default app;
```

The `App.svelte` like this:

```
<script>
  import mapboxgl from "mapbox-gl";
  mapboxgl.accessToken = 'token'
  const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: "map",
    style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10",
    center: [16.37, 48.2],
    zoom: 12,
  });
</script>

<svelte:head>
  <link
    href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-assembly/v0.23.2/assembly.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet"
  />
  <script
    src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-assembly/v0.23.2/assembly.js"></script>
</svelte:head>

<div id="map" />

<style>
  div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>
```

And thats it. Nothing is appearing. If I add:

```
...
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
...
```

This to the `index.html, then I see this:

So far from full screen. What am I missing?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when the Javascript of your component runs then the `<DIV id="map"/>` is not created yet. So the Mapbox call won't find a container to put the map into, and just quits.

When you put the `<DIV id="map"/>` in your `index.html` then the DIV was there but because of the CSS scoping of Svelte the CSS wasn't applied to it (because it's outside of your component) (see: https://svelte.dev/docs#style)
You can use the `:global` modifier in the CSS declaration to "fix" that and it should work.

But the better solution is to have the map creation code run at the correct part of the component life cycle: after the HTML is mounted in the DOM.

To do that you would need to use the `onMount` function from the `Svelte` library: (see: https://svelte.dev/docs#onMount)

```
  import { onMount } from 'svelte'
  import mapboxgl from "mapbox-gl";
  mapboxgl.accessToken = 'token'
  
  onMount(() => {
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: "map",
      style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10",
      center: [16.37, 48.2],
      zoom: 12,
    });     
  })
```